# Is there a way to get selenium to press down Command+Shift+C at the same time?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, pycharm

I'm trying to open Chrome in its mobile view on a Mac OS by pressing Command+Shift+c and then Command+Shift+m.

I am using Pycharm, with Python3 and Selenium. I've tried many different combinations, these are the three that I remember.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/y~~/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://instagram.com/")

keys = Keys()
actions = ActionChains(driver)

driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(keys.COMMAND + keys.SHIFT + 'c')
actions.key_down(keys.SHIFT).key_down(keys.COMMAND).send_keys('c').key_up(keys.SHIFT).key_up(keys.COMMAND).perform()
actions.send_keys(keys.COMMAND + keys.SHIFT +'c').perform()
```

By pressing the three buttons, the developer's toolbox should appear. and then I'll use the same to press cmd+shift+m which will open/show the mobile view.

Answer (score 0):

For opening the chrome in Mobile view you can refer below code .Reference [Mobile Emulation](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/mobile-emulation)

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

mobile_emulation = {

    "deviceMetrics": { "width": 360, "height": 640, "pixelRatio": 3.0 },

    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; en-us; Nexus 5 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19" }

chrome_options = Options()

chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/~location_of_chromedriver/chromedriver', chrome_options = chrome_options)
```

Comment: And what would I have to do if I wanted to change chrome into a Mobile view after doing some actions to the webpage?

Comment: Try using chrome Dev tools protocol in selenium 4 to change user agent . It's better to keep test related to Mobile view and desktop view separate.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in Chromedriver for MacOS which prevents many command-key combinations from working.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3023#c2

You can workaround by using Geckodriver, or running your tests in another OS.